# Have a different favion for browsers that support theme colour

Tags: google-chrome, favicon

I want to add a black favicon with a transparent background.

This is simple enough.

However, on the Chrome browser for mobile phones, there is a feature called theme colour:

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/11/Support-for-theme-color-in-Chrome-39-for-Android

This means I can change the colour of the window frame.

In this case, instead of a black favicon, I want a white favicon with a black theme colour.

Is this possible?